# Binomial Distribution problem $n$ and $p$ unknown

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution

$$X \sim B(n, p)$$

$$P(X=2)= \frac{80}{243} \quad \quad \quad P(X=5)= \frac{12}{729}$$

Find $n$ and $p$.

Why is $n=6$ and $p=\frac{1}{3}$?
We cannot use simultaneous equations. However, I think its something to do with $243 = 3^5$ but I am not too sure.

Comment: What is $P(X=k)$ for binomial distribution? You have two unknowns and two equations.

Comment: $P(X=x)= nCx p^x (1-p)^{n-x}$

Comment: I see the difficulty now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a unique solution of (n,p).
put n equal to a any integer greater than 5, you will find a particular p as a solution.

Comment: That was what I initially thought, until I tried to calculate the $n=7$ case.